# Install xdebug 2.1.4 on ubuntu server 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

I have tried to install xdebug on my ubuntu server machine and it's not working. The reason I know it's not working is that the output of var_dump is not colorized, nor can I connect to it using netbeans.

I followed the tailored instructions on how to install xdebug on

```
http://xdebug.org/wizard.php
```

Here is what the output of my phpinfo analysis was:

```
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.3.6-13
Zend API nr: 220090626
PHP API nr: 20090626
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path: /etc/php5/apache2
Configuration File: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Extensions directory: /usr/lib/php5/20090626
```

The name of the file that wizard recommended was xdebug-2.1.4.tgz

The output of phpize was

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

My phpinfo now does show xdebug installed, here is how it looks like:

[image]

Here is what I have in my php.ini

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/var/log/apache2/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable =1
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.2.13
xdebug.remote_port=9000
;xdebug.idekey=xdebug
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/apache2/xdebug_remote.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=9
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
```

The output of lsb_release -a on my computer is

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:        11.10
Codename:       oneiric
```

PHP version shown on phpinfo is 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the colours, you probably want to set `html_errors=1` in php.ini as well.

As for the netbeans issue (you really should not combine issues in one question!), which IP addresses do your machine running PHP, and which IP address does your machine running netbeans have? The xdebug.remote_host setting should contain the IP address of the one running netbeans. The remote log file that you're generating should have connection attempts in it too.